# Jquery execute onchange event on onload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that on change event run the post actions.

```
$("select#marca").change(function(){
    var marca = $("select#marca option:selected").attr('value');
    $("select#modello").html(attendere);
$.post("select.php", {id_marca:marca}, function(data){
        $("select#modello").html(data);
    });
});
```

I would like to perform this function onload event. Is it possible?
Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: You mean trigger the function on load? have you tryed: $("select#marca").change();

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Just put it in a function, then call it on document ready too, like so:

```
$(function () {
    yourFunction(); //this calls it on load
    $("select#marca").change(yourFunction);
});

function yourFunction() {
    var marca = $("select#marca option:selected").attr('value');
    $("select#modello").html(attendere);
    $.post("select.php", {id_marca:marca}, function(data){
        $("select#modello").html(data);
    });
}
```

Or just invoke `change` on page load?

```
$(function () {
    $("select#marca").change();
});
```

Comment: I tried $(window).load(function () {
$(function () {
    $("select#marca").change();
}); but the event not run..

Comment: @PaoloRossi `$(function()` will **already execute on page load** don't wrap it inside a `$(window).load` and make sure you have registered the `change` event before trying to fire `.change`

Answer (score 46):

Really simple way it to just chain another .change() event to the end of your on change function like this:

```
$("#yourElement").change(function(){
   // your code here
}).change(); // automatically execute the on change function you just wrote
```

Answer (score 19):

If you add `.change()` to the end it will be called straight away after being bound:

```
$(function() { 
    $("select#marca").change(function(){
        var marca = $("select#marca option:selected").attr('value');
        $("select#modello").html(attendere);
    $.post("select.php", {id_marca:marca}, function(data){
            $("select#modello").html(data);
        });
    }).change(); // Add .change() here
});
```

Or change the callback to an actual function and call that:

```
function marcaChange(){
    var marca = $("select#marca option:selected").attr('value');
    $("select#modello").html(attendere);
$.post("select.php", {id_marca:marca}, function(data){
        $("select#modello").html(data);
    });
}

$(function() { 
    $("select#marca").change(marcaChange);
    marcaChange();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To call `onload`, you can try jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 onchange();// onload it will call the function
     });
```

Write your onchange function like this, so this will be called when `onchange` occurs,

```
function onchange(){
    var marca = $("select#marca option:selected").attr('value');
    $("select#modello").html(attendere);
    $.post("select.php", {id_marca:marca}, function(data){
    $("select#modello").html(data);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

this is working for me.

```
 $(function () {
    $('#checkboxId').on('change', hideShowfunction).trigger('change');
});

function hideShowfunction(){
//handle your checkbox check/uncheck logic here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other way to do

```
 $("select#marca").val('your_value').trigger('change');
```