# When does the jquery change function trigger?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Referring to this post: [Jquery execute onchange event on onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984598/jquery-execute-onchange-event-on-onload)

I got the opposite Problem.
This was my first attempt but the function executes on page load
I excpected it to trigger on the first change.

```
function get_items(){
    alert("hello");
};
$('#select_field').change(get_items());
```

This one works and there is only an alert if i really change the select_field:

```
$('#select_field').change(function(){
    get_items();
});
```

It is probably some basic stuff but i cant find anything helpfull.
Can someone pls explain whats happening here?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#select_field').change(get_items());` should be `$('#select_field').change(get_items);`

Binding event handlers requires passing a function *reference*. When you call `get_items()` you're *executing* the function.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually calling the function.Change your code like this

```
$('#select_field').change(get_items);
```

This will only fire when the value changes.