# Run script on loading DropDownListFor

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view with the following line of code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FrequencyTypes, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.FreqTypes, null, new { @onchange = "toggleOptionalDisplay(this.value)", @class = "form-control" })
```

This works great for when the drop down is changed but I can't work out how to run the script when the drop down is first loaded.

Comment: There is no onload event for drop down in jquery. Instead the onchange event is fired on dropdown load. This link may help you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984598/jquery-execute-onchange-event-on-onload

Comment: I think I need to read up some more on jquery as that link didn't make total sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by changing the drop down to:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FrequencyTypes, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.FreqTypes, null, new { @onchange = "toggleOptionalDisplay(this.value)", @class = "form-control", @id = "freqtype", @style = "width:300px;" })
```

and adding the following extra script (which calls my original function):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        toggleOptionalDisplay($("#freqtype").val());
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could helped you, but this approach uses jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('select[name="FrequencyTypes"]').change(); 
});
```

Comment: Would this jquery run when the page loads?

Comment: Hi @AndrewLackenby, I changed the code to use `$(document).ready(function() { });` to be more easier to understand