# Trigger a jQuery function on document.ready

Tags: jquery

I have a bit of Javascript within my .change() function and would like to apply the same code within the function on the .ready() function. Is there any way I could achive this, without copy and pasting the code into the function aswell?

```
$('.selabw').change(function(){

     let that = $(this);
     let value = that.parent().next().prev().find('select').val();
     console.log('"' + value + '"');

     if(value == ''){
       that.parent().next().find('input').removeClass('disabledBetrag').removeAttr('disabled');
     } else {
       that.parent().next().find('input').val('0,00');
       that.parent().next().find('input').attr('disabled', 'true').addClass('disabledBetrag');
     }

});



$(document).ready( function(){
// trigger $('.selabw').change(function(){}); ? 
}
```

Comment: See this stackoverflow link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984598/jquery-execute-onchange-event-on-onload/14984648

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this.

```
$('.selabw').trigger('change')
```

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: sorry for the late reply. thank you very much for your answer. exactly what I needed!