# How to set field as required if value exist in other field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have first, last name, and email input fields. The requirement from the customer is to have email field required only if either first or last name value exist. If there is no value entered in either of those two fields email should not be required. I have developed this code that works assuming that form is always empty. The problem is the case when user already has data entered in there and user is loading the form. In that case my code is not useful. Here is working example of what I have so far.

```js
$(".check").on("keyup blur", function() {
  var fldVal = $(this).val();

  if (fldVal) {
    $("#email").closest("div").addClass("required");
    $("#email").prop("required", true);
  } else {
    $("#email").closest("div").removeClass("required");
    $("#email").prop("required", false);
  }
});
```

```css
.row {padding: 3px;}
.required label:after { content: " *"; color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="text" id="test">
  <div class="row">
    <label>First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="first" id="first" class="check">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label>Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="last" id="last" class="check">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
  </div>
  <button type="button" name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I would like for my code to check all the requirements on page load. If possible that should all be done with one function. I can't think of a good way to achieve that. Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: Just trigger "keyup" or "blur" on a field in the document ready event.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Example please.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function () { $('.check').trigger('keyup'); })`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jquery execute onchange event on onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984598/jquery-execute-onchange-event-on-onload)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes, thanks for your help!